# Removing SVN username and password from Eclipse does not work in Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, svn, windows-7

I'm using Eclipse (Helios) 32Bit in Windows 7, with Subclipse 1.6.x.

I want to reset my SVN username and password. On the internet, I found the following steps:

> - Close Eclipse or RAD/WSAD
> - Navigate to the following directory replacing {User} with your Windows logon id.
> - C:\Documents and Settings{User}\Application Data\Subversion
> - Delete all files under the Subversion directory
> - Open Eclipse or RAD/WSAD
> - Synchronize with your SVN repository
> - If prompted click Accept Permanently to trust the certificate
> - When prompted enter your Subverion user id and password

These steps aren't working. When I open Eclipse again and synchronize with the repository, it doesn't ask for a username or password.

---

**Other information:**

- I tried deleting the files in the `Subversion` directory, but when synchronizing, Eclipse creates a folder there again.
- In another post I read about "deleting the `.keyring` file", but I couldn't find the location of this file.
- In the Secure Storage contents tab, I only have this:

  [image]

Answer (score 17):

There are different possibilities where passwords could be stored in eclipse and subversion. The keyring file is stored in an installation of eclipse I have used with subclipse at `<root>/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.keyring`. You should at least look if it exists there. The location of that file may be overriden by command line parameters, but that you would know. See the article ["How to change Eclipse SVN plugin password"](http://www.techcrony.info/2008/03/26/admin/how-to-change-eclipse-svn-password/) for some more information.

For another option, you could check:

1. Go into the Preferences by `Windows > Preferences`.
2. Select there `General > Security > Secure Storage`.
3. Go to the tab `Contents` and expand there the entry `SVN`.

[image]

You should see now a local cache of SVN related things that SVN can use to answer the password question for the server. Delete the entries that is cached for the location you want to login as a different user. Ensure that your subversion directory is cleaned as well:

- Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\{User}\Application Data\Subversion`
- Windows 7: `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`

And delete the `.keyring` file as well, if you find it.

Comment: mmm what is 'expand there the entry SVN.' i could not find it . when i go to tab 'content' it has  a table 'ID' and 'value' , but no values there

Answer (score 0):

I've found the fil containig my SVN credentials at ...\Eclipse\config\auth\svn.simple\

Answer (score 0):

https://casecomplete.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200685197-Resetting-stored-Subversion-credentials

This worked for me. deleting all the files, in the svn.simple directory (for windows 7) deletes all the stored passwords. One will have to set them, while commiting content again, but that is obviously through the usual means.