# Trying to sycnrhonize SVN in eclipse is no longer prompting me for password

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using Eclipse with the SVN plugin. 
I was trying to do a synchronize on my workspace from the Team Synchronization tab.  It prompted me for a password. I entered the incorrect password and I got the following error. So I tried to do a syncrhonization again, but it is no longer prompting me for the password.  How do I make Eclipse SVN either prompt me for the password again?????????????

THank you

Authentication error.
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/path: 401 Authorization Required (https://path..com)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. What worked for me was clearing secure storage contents in Eclipse as described here: [Removing SVN username and password from Eclipse does not work in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342206/3387811).

Quoting from the linked answer:

> - Go into the Preferences by Windows > Preferences.
> - Select there General > Security > Secure Storage.
> - Go to the tab Contents and expand there the entry SVN.

- Then Click the "Delete" button.

Clicking on "Delete" there cleared all of my Secure Storage, which I did not itend, but didn't care much about either. At least the prompt showed up again and I was able to enter my user name / password.

Be sure to check the link as there are also other options for resetting password caches mentioned there, which I did not have to try out though, as this method worked.